# How to add an entry to a map in TypeScript using the set method with 'Cannot read properties of undefined' error?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add an entry into a map in typescript ,so i am using set method but it is showing cannot read properties of undefined

i created a variable named users(line no 65) in which i want to add number corresponding to user name(line no 79),but it is showing the error that  Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')[focus on line 65 and 79](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iftnL.png)

Comment: Yeah because users is still undefined. It doesn't matter that you added ! to ignore it is undefined ;) you should create the instance instead of just defining the variable: ... = new Map<a, b>();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) or the question might be closed as needing details or clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try assigning new map object when you declare users:

```
users!: Map<string, Number> = new Map<string, Number>();
```

And for next time, please, put some code in your post instead of image. Or if you post image, at least give us full picture. You refer to number of liners, but they're not even visible in your screenshot